# formula to substitute all rows containing # or numbers or semicolon

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

so for example I have the following

A-column

text;#22

text;#23

text;#23

I want to write a formula on that A column to substitute all rows that contains digits 0-9 or ; or #

So the result would be:
A-column

text

text

text

However, I cannot get it to work as I keep getting an excel error, will someone help me with this plz?

This is what I have found and tried but it gives an error:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TableName[[#This Row],[A]],"0",""),"1",""),"2",""),"3",""),"4",""),"5",""),"6",""),"7",""),"8",""),"9",""),";#;#","; "),";#","")
```

Comment: At a guess, it doesn't like `TableName[[#This Row],[A]]`. Try replacing that with a cell reference, such as `A1`.

Comment: Is your sample data so heavily redacted that `=LEFT(TableName[@A], FIND(";", TableName[@A]&";"))` will not worK? btw, that and your formula has to be on the same worksheet row as a row within the table to work.

Comment: OK ... `=LEFT(TableName[@A], FIND(";", TableName[@A]&";")-1)` then.

Comment: Tried both suggestions, yet still getting an error. @Phylogenesis

Comment: Is a VBA solution acceptable for you?

Comment: don't mind as long as it works. @ozy

Comment: These formulas are working in my computer, it makes me curious the reason for not working in yours. Could you please post a sample with the real values in your table for column A and the formulas results at least 3 of them. Also when you said it gives an error, what kind of error, i.e. it does not accept the formula, the formula returns an error, or the results are in error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions in vba so you can match and replace many complex patterns. Firstly, I created a module under visual basic editor and add this `cellRegex` vba function. Second, you need to add reference to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` from the visual basic editor menu `Tools>References`.

```vb
Function cellRegex(Myrange As Range, strPattern As String, Optional strReplace As String) As String
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strInput As String

    If IsMissing(strReplace) Then
        strReplace = ""
    End If

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = Myrange.Value

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.test(strInput) Then
            cellRegex = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
        Else
            cellRegex = "!No Match!"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

After all, you will be able to call your function from any cell. Below is the formula you want. First argument is the cell containing text, second argument is the regex pattern to match and third argument, that is optional, is the replace string (in your case it is empty string)

`=cellRegex(A1;"[;#0-9]*";"")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to replace the string. In JavaScript, the regex is pretty simple:

```
textSub = function(str) {
  return str.replace(/[;0-9#]*/g, '');
};
```

Then, use formula =textSub(A1).

Example:

http://dtab.io/sheets/560b75a008fbb3ec18e5b1bf